# How to test a method that makes calls to a database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, mocking

I have several methods that make connections to a database and I can't figure out how to write unit tests for them. Here is a sample of what I'm talking about.

```
public static User GetByPendingUserId(int a_PendingUserId)
{
    User l_User = new User();
    SqlConnection l_conn = DbHelp.CreateSqlConnection();
    SqlCommand l_cmd = DbHelp.CreateCommand(l_conn, "User_Get");
    l_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_PendingUserId", a_PendingUserId);
    DataTable l_result = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter l_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(l_cmd);
    l_conn.Open();
    l_adapter.Fill(l_result);
    l_conn.Close();
    l_adapter.Dispose();
    l_cmd.Dispose();
    if (l_result.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        User.SetMembers(l_result.Rows[0], l_User);
    }
    return l_User;
}
```

Since I am writing a unit test and not an integration test, I want to test the logic of the method without connecting to an actual database. How can I do this?

Comment: related, btw it is usually called integration testing when other environment is affected (the database) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133448/unit-integration-testing-my-dal

Comment: Majority of this method is framework calls - do you really see a point in testing those with a unit test? These only go wrong if the  DbHelp methods go wrong.

Comment: I agree that this particular method doesn't need a whole lot of testing, but I'm just using it as an example. There are other more complicated methods that use this same pattern for retrieving data from the database, but they are hundreds of lines long. I just didn't feel like posting a code snippet that large in the question.

Comment: Mock the connection or the IDbCommand and setup a mocked database that starts a transaction and setups all initial data and at the teardown just rollback the transaction. You cold also use a second database, but should make sure that database structure is as identical as possible to reality.

Comment: Wait, so do you actually want to test the database methods or test the code that relies on the the database methods? Because as @bradbury9 says, the former would be integration tests not unit tests. My answer is related to the latter.

Comment: I want to test the code that relies on the database methods. I may have chosen my example poorly.

Comment: @tayopi Cool, you may want to edit the question to make that slightly clearer. My answer should be useful to you hopefully .

Comment: @pmcilreavy Thanks for suggestion. If the wording on the question still doesn't seem clear, please feel free to add your own edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to test the code that relies on these methods one way you could achieve this is by using the *Repository* pattern. You encapsulate data access for a given section of you system into an abstraction called a repository. So in your case you may have a *user repository* which would be comprised of the following interface for instance and a corresponding implementation.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetByPendingUserId(int a_PendingUserId)
}
```

Note that `GetByPendingUserId` can't be static anymore.

You can now implement this interface. So your actual production implementation might look like this:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User GetByPendingUserId(int a_PendingUserId)
    {
        User l_User = new User();
        SqlConnection l_conn = DbHelp.CreateSqlConnection();
        SqlCommand l_cmd = DbHelp.CreateCommand(l_conn, "User_Get");
        l_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_PendingUserId", a_PendingUserId);
        DataTable l_result = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter l_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(l_cmd);
        l_conn.Open();
        l_adapter.Fill(l_result);
        l_conn.Close();
        l_adapter.Dispose();
        l_cmd.Dispose();
        if (l_result.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            User.SetMembers(l_result.Rows[0], l_User);
        }
        return l_User;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes you can now implement a another version of this that returns whatever data you like to fit the goal of your test. Maybe it just returns a `new User`. It's up to you. The point is you no longer have a dependency on an actual database and you can focus on testing the logic of your application in your unit tests.

```
public class TestUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User GetByPendingUserId(int a_PendingUserId)
    {
        return new User()
    }
}
```

Once you have more interfaces like these in place you can then look at using a mocking framework which gives you more flexibility around testing specific scenarios.