# How to test a method that relies on some data from database without having to make interfaces for all methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

i am new to writing tests and i am stuck with the following problem.

I have a service class with a public method that runs some validation based off database data and returns a bool, something like this

```
public async Task<bool> IsSessionAllowed(SessionAlowedReq req)
{
        var data = await GetFromDB(/* some params*/);
        //process data... 
        return results;
}
```

GetFromDB is a private method that makes a db call and returns some obj which i then process in the IsSessionAllowed method and check some business rules and return a bool.

Now im not trying to test GetFromDB method (i understand that would be more integration test) what i am trying to do is given different results from the GetFromDB method to test whether IsSessionAllowed returns correct results. The one way i found to do this is [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176644/21475760) which basically makes me turn all private methods (in this scenerio) into a new interface and have the test class provide its own implementation of it. i find it not clean at all for methods that would never be used on their own to have their own interfaces just for testing purposes

So is there another way to do this?

EDIT:
here's how my private method works

```
 private async Task<dynamic?> GetFromDB(/* params */)
{
        //there are multiple DBs this returns the correct DbContext based on string
        DbContext db = _contextFactory.GetContext("some db");
        return await db.Set<TableName>()
            .Where(n =>
                n.ClientId == clientId &&
                n.StateId == stateId &&
                n.NoteDate.HasValue && n.NoteDate.Value.Date <= date.Date
            )
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: How do you call the database? There must be some kind of database object, doesn't it? You'd replace this database object

Comment: i understand what your saying, im just not sure how that would  be implemented. i added the private method implementation if it helps

Comment: You can mock even a private method using an unconstrained framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688. But this is not the recommended way. / Have you read the documentation? [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thanks, so these options work but are not recommended so is the recommeneded approach to create interfaces even when these methods will never be used in isolation? or is there another way?

Comment: for unitests you if haven't get any database available so you mock the database respond

Comment: @knittl i added the method that calls the DB mind sharing some resources explaining your comment or leaving a answer? would be really really appreciated.

Comment: @Quak_2023 `_contextFactory` is something that you can replace with a test double. But it looks like a complex class, so you might fare better by moving the complete method body to a separate class which you can then replace by a test double.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is about testing that specific `IsSessionAllowed` method, then you can use this technique:

Make `GetFromDB` protected virtual.
Create a testable sub-class of the class that contains `GetFromDB`:

```
public class TestableSession: SessionClass
{

    protected override Task<dynamic?> GetFromDB()
    {
        // return fake data
        return Task.FromResult<dynamic?>(null);
    }
 }
```

Then create `TestableSession` as SUT instead of the real `SessionClass`.

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
     var sut = new TestableSession();
     sut.IsSessionAllowed(req);
}
```

While you will likely need to test other methods that interact with DbContext, the best choices are to use the Repository Pattern or create integration tests that involve a real database, as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/